# In Pine-Script, how do I code two conditions for my entry?

Tags: conditional-statements, pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, multiple-conditions

Could someone please help as I need entry conditions to include the BraidFilter indicator into my strategy. I only need a trade entry long when the green bars and short entry when the red bars cross over the filter line. This is what I did but it's not working and I'm getting a ton of error messages:
Please help. Thank you.

```
//-- Braid Filter   
ma01 = ma(maType, close, Period1)
ma02 = ma(maType, open, Period2)
ma03 = ma(maType, close, Period3)

max  = max(max(ma01, ma02), ma03)
min  = min(min(ma01, ma02), ma03)
dif  = max - min

filter = atr(14) * PipsMinSepPercent / 100

//-- Plots/=
//BraidColor = ma01 > ma02 and dif > filter ? color.green : ma02 > ma01 and dif > filter ? color.red : color.gray

//plot(dif, "Braid", BraidColor, 5, plot.style_columns)
//plot(filter, "Filter", color.blue, 2, plot.style_line)
//bgcolor(BraidColor)

// Condition
C1Price1 = 0.0
C1Price2 = 0.0
C1Price1 := ? ma01 > ma02 and dif > filter
C1Price2 := ? ma02 > ma01 and dif > filter

c1Cross_Long    =  crossover (C1Price1,C1Price2) and C1Price1 > filter
c1Cross_Short   =  crossover (C1Price1,C1Price2) and C1Price2 > filter
```

Answer (score 0):

There are things missing in that code, first you have to define the script with a strategy, then define the maType variable, in addition to that:

```
C1Price1: =**?** ma01> ma02 and dif> filter
C1Price2: =**?** ma02> ma01 and dif> filter
```

prior to "?" There must be a condition to meet, I think something was deleted there, after correcting that you will have to write the entries.

Comment: I actually just copied those lines from the above line "Braidcolor" in //plots, thinking it was going to work.

Comment: This is part of my whole strategy so the "study()" is found above the code, what I posted was just for the indicator. So I need to look for the conditions rules?